# SSH2 library, how to execute unix commands from NODE

Tags: javascript, node.js, unix, ssh

I am trying to understand about the SSH2 for nodeJS https://github.com/mscdex/ssh2, but I can't find more documentation, does anybody has more related to the client events?

I am trying to connect from my Node project to a Unix server and execute commands from node using this library SSH2 such as mkdir, ls or some other unix commands but I can't find any documentation of how to do it.

I am able to establish connection, but now I need to execute unix commands

```
var Client = require('ssh2').Client;
//
var conn = new Client();
conn.on('ready', function() {
    console.log('Client :: ready');
    conn.sftp(function(err, sftp) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('Client :: SSH open');
        output.add("ls");
        conn.end();
    });
}).connect({
    host: 'hostname',
    port: 22,
    username: 'user',
    password: 'password'
});
```

Or if this is not achievable with SSH2 can somebody recommend another Node Library were I can connect to an unix server? I have a Node application that creates a HTML file but after the creation I need to name it in base of the last file name that I have in a unix server, create the directory in unix and the upload it using sftp-upload plugin. Trying to achieve this with node instead of doing manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with [node-exec](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ssh-exec) or [ssh2-exec](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ssh2-exec) which uses `ssh2`. `ssh2` is low level so for exec you can use other libs like `ssh2-exec` and `ssh2-connect`.

There are plenty of examples in `README.md`.

Example (from `ssh2-exec README`):

> ```
> connect = require('ssh2-connect');
> exec = require('ssh2-exec');
> connect({host: localhost}, function(err, ssh){
>   child = exec({cmd: 'ls -la', ssh: ssh}, function(err, stdout, stderr){
>     console.log(stdout);
>   });
>   child.stdout.on('data', function(data){
>     console.log(stdout);
>   });
>   child.on('exit', function(code){
>     console.log('Exit', code);
>   });
> })
> ```